# How to change variable at module with angular schematics?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

Just like `addImportToModule` or `addProviderToModul`,my module file look like this:

```
const EXAMPLES = [
    ButtonIconExampleComponent,
    ButtonTextExampleComponent,
    ButtonDashedExampleComponent
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: EXAMPLES,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    entryComponents: EXAMPLES,
    exports: EXAMPLES,
    providers: []
})
export class ExamplesModule {}
```

variable `EXAMPLES` can be used many times,so I want to change it with schematics utils function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a global variable by exporting it using `export` then you can use it everywhere in `.ts` files.

Comment: Well,but my only need is just push a variable to `const EXAMPLES` when run schematic.